# Outlook desktop Addin not working with bearer token

Tags: .net, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have developed an outlook add-in which is hosted on one domain say "https://domainId" communicates with an api on hosted on another domain "https://domain2". It gets the token from domain and uses it to fetch other data using a bearer token fetched from domain2. This all works fine on outlook web. But the issue comes when it tries to fetch the data from the api using the bearer token. It throws a Network Error for all request involving the bearer token.

I included the domain in the manifest AppDomains list but still it throws that error.
Both domains are https and even cors are enabled

Need help to resolve this issue

Comment: Appdomians should be the way to solve this issue. You may want to use fiddler to inspect the network request and analyze (or post here) the error that you are seeing. Also fiddler may reveal additional domains that need to be added to appdomins.

Comment: this is the error i m getting from  IE11
"SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied"

Comment: Are you using the rich native Desktop Outlook client, or are you using the Outlook Web client in a browser? Also, this error appears to be specific to CORS. Can you try this code outside an Outlook add-in; in other words, in a simple webpage that is not an Outlook add-in and see if you can repro this issue? This will help determine whether it is specific to the Outlook Add-ins environment or not.

Comment: solved it..needed to explicitly specify the headers in the api project as it was not taking wildcard "*" character..normally for older browsers 

thanks

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the issue.